# I am getting the error message Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am getting the error message

**Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.in Login (created by Context.Consumer`)**

I am have tried the most common fix for that issue but it didn't work. The fix where you use _isMounted = false; componentDidMount() { this._isMounted = true;}  if (this._isMounted) {this.setState({ data: data});}

I am also using Context.

**SessionContex.js**

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from "react";

export const SessionContext = createContext();

class SessionContextProvider extends Component {
  _isMounted = false;
  state = {
    is_logged_in: false,
    personid: " ",
    firstname: " ",
    lastname: " "
  };
  loggedIn = (loginvalue, personid, firstname, lastname) => {
    this.setState({
      is_logged_in: loginvalue,
      personid: personid,
      firstname: firstname,
      lastname: lastname
    });
  };

  loggedOut = () => {
    this.setState({
      is_logged_in: false,
      personid: " ",
      firstname: " ",
      lastname: " "
    });
  };
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this._isMounted = true;
    const login = localStorage.getItem("is_logged");
    const id = localStorage.getItem("personid");
    const firstname = localStorage.getItem("firtname");
    const lastname = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
    console.log(login);
    if (this._isMounted) {
      this.setState({
        is_logged_in: login,
        personid: id,
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname
      });
    }
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <SessionContext.Provider
        value={{
          ...this.state,
          loggedIn: this.loggedIn,
          loggedOut: this.loggedOut
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </SessionContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default SessionContextProvider;
```

**Login.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { SessionContext } from "../context/SessionContext";
import "../Stylesheets/Login.css";
import "..//Stylesheets/global.css";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

class Login extends Component {
  _isMounted = false;
  static contextType = SessionContext;

  state = {
    password: " ",
    email: " ",
    couldNotfindLogin: true,
    redirect: false
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = this.state;
    console.log(data);
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3080/users/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });

    const reply = await response;

    if (reply.status === 200) {
      const userData = await response.json();
      this.context.loggedIn(
        userData.isValid,
        userData.personid,
        userData.firstname,
        userData.lastname
      );
      localStorage.setItem("is_logged", userData.isValid);
      localStorage.setItem("personid", userData.personid);
      localStorage.setItem("firstname", userData.firstname);
      localStorage.setItem("lastname", userData.lastname);

      this.setState({
        couldNotfindLogin: true,
        redirect: true
      });
    }

    if (reply.status !== 200) {
      this.context.loggedIn(false);
      console.log(this.context);
    }
    this.setState({
      couldNotfindLogin: false
    });
  };
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mounted = false;
  }

  render() {
    let { couldNotfindLogin } = this.state;
    if (this.state.redirect === true) {
      return <Redirect to="/" />;
    }

    return (
      <>
        <section className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 login-section">
              <div className="form login-box">
                <form className="form-login Login" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <label htmlFor="Email">
                    <p className="login-header">
                      Login to see your past, present, and future self.
                    </p>
                    <input
                      className="login-input"
                      id="Email"
                      type="text"
                      name="email"
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                      placeholder="Email Address"
                      required
                    />
                    {!couldNotfindLogin ? (
                      <p className="FindYou">We could not find your account </p>
                    ) : (
                      " "
                    )}
                  </label>
                  <label htmlFor="Password">
                    <input
                      className="login-input"
                      id="Password"
                      type="password"
                      name="password"
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                      placeholder="Password"
                      required
                    />
                  </label>
                  <button className="login-button" type="submit">
                    Login
                  </button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a few mistakes that are holding you back. I'll try to brief as to not make this a long-winded answer:

- Allow the `Provider` to handle all things related to high-level `state` and `localStorage`. Only use local state that's revelant to the component. Also, since `setState()` is asynchronous, avoid setting it immediately following another asynchronous function(s). While you do have an `_isMounted` class property, it isn't being checked against when the async function (fetch request) resolves, therefore if you're redirecting the user to another route while React attempts to update the component state, then you'll get these warnings as described above. Put simply, utilize the `_isMounted` in the async function right before using setState or simply avoid using setState (see example below).
- The `handleChange` class field only needs a single `[e.target.name]: e.target.value` statement. Having two is unnecessary. You can use [object destructuring](https://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/) to simplify this down to: `[name]: value` (see example below).
- Any `component` provided to a `Route` has access to some [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props). Among the props is a `history` object that contains several methods -- among them is a `push` method. You can use this `push` method to redirect a user to another url: `this.props.history.push("url")`. Again this is provided, by default, to a **component** that resides in a react-router-dom **Route**.
- `async/await` will only work on [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Therefore, you'll want to `await` the initial fetch `response` and then `await` the fetch `response.json()` promise. The first promise, returns a **Stream object**, while the second promise returns a **JSON object** (this is by design, other libraries, like [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), skip this second promise). Therefore, `const reply = await response;` expression isn't necessary as it's not waiting for promise a resolve, but instead it's just setting the response's **Stream object** to a `reply` variable.
- Lastly, only use `let` for variables if you plan on updating or mutating this variable dynamically within the same execution cycle; otherwise, just use `const`. This becomes especially important because `state` and `props` should always be [immutable](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5/) for React to know when or if they have been updated (via another component or by `setState`). Simply put, avoid using `let` for state/prop expressions like: `let { password } = this.state`.

**Working example** (I'm mimicking the `fetch` response promise, but you can play around with it by checking out the **src/api/index.js** file -- for example you can trigger an error response by submitting a password as `invalid`):

[image: Edit polished-sun-hqlt5]

Comment: Thank you for that response. That helped me clean up my code a lot. I am still getting the error message, but I think might just do some refactoring.

Comment: As I detailed in the first bullet point, you're getting that error because you're unmounting the component while setting state (most likely due to the async handleSubmit class field).